# Python code runs two times

Tags: python, repeat

I am trying to make a rock paper scissors game in python while trying to implement a point system for victories / losses. when I run the code, I get asked to choose rock paper or scissors, i pick my answer but then i get asked again for some reason, could anyone help me out? (I'm pretty much a beginner)

```
from random import randint
def RPS():
    UserPts = 0
    AIPts = 0
    def Game():
        moves = ["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]
        def genAImove():
            genai = moves[randint(0,2)]
            return genai
        genAImove()
        AImove = genAImove()
        def genUserMove():
            genu = raw_input("Choose your move ('Rock','Paper' or 'Scissors')\n")
            return genu
        genUserMove()
        UserMove = genUserMove()        
        if UserMove == "Rock" and AImove == "Rock":
            print "The AI chose rock too.\nDraw."
            def cont():
                cnt = raw_input("Do you want to continue? (Y\N)")
                if cnt == "Y":
                    Game()
                elif cnt == "N":
                    exit
                else:
                    print "Pick Y or N"
                    cont()
            cont()
        if UserMove == "Rock" and AImove == "Paper":
            print "The AI chose paper.\nLoss."

            def cont():
                cnt = raw_input("Do you want to continue? (Y\N)")
                if cnt == "Y":
                    Game()
                elif cnt == "N":
                    exit
                else:
                    print "Pick Y or N"
                    cont()
            cont()
        if UserMove == "Rock" and AImove == "Scissors":
            print "The AI chose scissors.\nWin."

            def cont():
                cnt = raw_input("Do you want to continue? (Y\N)")
                if cnt == "Y":
                    Game()
                elif cnt == "N":
                    exit
                else:
                    print "Pick Y or N"
                    cont()
            cont()
        if UserMove == "Paper" and AImove == "Rock":
            print "The AI chose rock.\nWin."

            def cont():
                cnt = raw_input("Do you want to continue? (Y\N)")
                if cnt == "Y":
                    Game()
                elif cnt == "N":
                    exit
                else:
                    print "Pick Y or N"
                    cont()
            cont()
        if UserMove == "Paper" and AImove == "Paper":
            print "The AI chose paper.\nDraw."

            def cont():
                cnt = raw_input("Do you want to continue? (Y\N)")
                if cnt == "Y":
                    Game()
                elif cnt == "N":
                    exit
                else:
                    print "Pick Y or N"
                    cont()
            cont()
        if UserMove == "Paper" and AImove == "Scissors":
            print "The AI chose scissors.\nLoss."

            def cont():
                cnt = raw_input("Do you want to continue? (Y\N)")
                if cnt == "Y":
                    Game()
                elif cnt == "N":
                    exit
                else:
                    print "Pick Y or N"
                    cont()
            cont()
        if UserMove == "Scissors" and AImove == "Rock":
            print "The AI chose rock.\nLoss."

            def cont():
                cnt = raw_input("Do you want to continue? (Y\N)")
                if cnt == "Y":
                    Game()
                elif cnt == "N":
                    exit
                else:
                    print "Pick Y or N"
                    cont()
            cont()
        if UserMove == "Scissors" and AImove == "Paper":
            print "The AI chose paper.\nWin."

            def cont():
                cnt = raw_input("Do you want to continue? (Y\N)")
                if cnt == "Y":
                    Game()
                elif cnt == "N":
                    exit
                else:
                    print "Pick Y or N"
                    cont()
            cont()
        if UserMove == "Scissors" and AImove == "Scissors":
            print "The AI chose scissors.\nDraw."

            def cont():
                cnt = raw_input("Do you want to continue? (Y\N)")
                if cnt == "Y":
                    Game()
                elif cnt == "N":
                    exit
                else:
                    print "Pick Y or N"
                    cont()
            cont()
    Game()
RPS()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these lines:

```
genUserMove()
UserMove = genUserMove()
```

You first call `genUserMove`, which asks you, and then *call it again*, and assign the result.

Just remove the first line.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, it fixed my problem. I over-complicated this  because I didn't know how global variables actually worked, that's why  I made  a function in a function but came across the same global variable problem, researched it a bit more and realised my mistakes and now my game is functional with points too, although with a lot more code than needed.